# Flutter Google Map increase marker icon size when being selected

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

Is there any way to increase the icon size of the marker in the map when being selected?

I've tried putting `List<BitmapDescriptor>` where it composes of two `bitmapDescriptor` so I can easily call the bitmap if I need to show the small/big version of the icon

```
bitmapDescriptor[0] // small
bitmapDescriptor[1] // big
```

but I think setState doesn't work in Markers that's is why it's not updating the icon.

**code:**

```
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(lBusLoc[index].businessID.toString()),
        position: LatLng(lBusLoc[index].latitude, lBusLoc[index].longitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: '', snippet: '${bus.busName}'),
        icon: selectedBusId == bus.busId //condition
            ? bitmapDescriptor[1] //big
            : bitmapDescriptor[0], //small
        onTap: ()  {
         
          setState(() {
            selectedBusId = bus.busId;       
          });
        },
      ),
```

is there any better way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `Marker` isn't a stateful widget so `setState` won't work with it. In fact it's not a Widget at all (it's a `MapObject`) so it has no builder method.

Whenever you tap a marker, you will need to replace your list of `Markers` with a new list and then use `setState` to rebuild the `GoogleMap` widget (which IS a stateful widget), using your new list of markers.

The code snippet below displays a set of blue icon markers. When you tap one it rebuilds all the markers setting the `BitmapDescriptor` of the selected pin to a green icon (you can just substitute green/blue icons with large/small `BitmapDescriptors`)

Hope this helps you solve your problem

```
final greenPin =
    BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen);
final bluePin = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue);

class MyMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyMapPage();

  @override
  _MyMapPageState createState() => _MyMapPageState();
}

class _MyMapPageState extends State<MyMapPage> {
  var pinList = [
    MarkerDetails(1, LatLng(52, 1), bigIcon: greenPin, smallIcon: bluePin),
    MarkerDetails(2, LatLng(52, 1.1), bigIcon: greenPin, smallIcon: bluePin),
    MarkerDetails(3, LatLng(52, 1.2), bigIcon: greenPin, smallIcon: bluePin),
    MarkerDetails(4, LatLng(52, 1.3), bigIcon: greenPin, smallIcon: bluePin),
  ];
  var markerList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    markerList = _generateMarkerList(pinList, 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        markers: Set.from(markerList),
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: pinList[0].position, zoom: 9),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Marker> _generateMarkerList(
      List<MarkerDetails> detailsList, int selectedKey) {
    return detailsList
        .map((place) => Marker(
              position:
                  LatLng(place.position.latitude, place.position.longitude),
              markerId: MarkerId(place.key.toString()),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: place.key.toString(), snippet: place.toString()),
              onTap: () => setState(() =>
                  markerList = _generateMarkerList(detailsList, place.key)),
              icon: selectedKey == place.key ? place.bigIcon : place.smallIcon,
            ))
        .toList();
  }
}

class MarkerDetails {
  final int key;
  final LatLng position;
  final BitmapDescriptor bigIcon;
  final BitmapDescriptor smallIcon;
  MarkerDetails(this.key, this.position,
      {@required this.bigIcon, @required this.smallIcon});
}
```